# Limit of hard multivariable function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have this crazy limit that I just can't seem to figure out why the answer is 0. Here is the limit:

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  (x+y+4)e^{-1/(x^2+y^2)} $$

This evaluates to 0. I would write out my steps but they are pretty pointless considering I always stop when I see that the derivative will give me x or y in denominator giving a undefined answer. Please go step by step because I can do almost any other limit but this one is killing me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $r=\bigl\|(x,y)\bigr\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then both $|x|$ and $|y|$ are smaller thatn or equal to $r$ and therefore$$|x+y+4|\leqslant|x|+|y|+4\leqslant r+4.$$Therefore$$\left|(x+y+4)e^{-\frac1{x^2+y^2}}\right|\leqslant(r+4)e^{-\frac1{r^2}}.$$Since $\lim_{r\to0}(r+4)e^{-\frac1{r^2}}=0$, the limit that you're after is $0$.

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  (x+y+4)e^{(-1/(x^2+y^2))}=4\cdot e^{-\infty}=4 \cdot 0=0$

Comment: but when e^(1/0) does this imply it is equal to 0?

Comment: Luke, $-1/0=-\infty$ and $e=2.72$, so $(2.72)^{-\infty}=(1/2.72)^{\infty}=0$ @Luke